# I made a http post request in client side(angular 8) but getting undefined in server side(node.js)

Tags: node.js, http, angular8

I am using angular 8 as front end framework, I was trying to do a http post request to send login details(object), which is not null or undefined, but on server side the request body of post is undefined. I am using nodejs on server side.

client side-> service.ts:

```
register( details:any){
    const url="http://localhost:4000/register";
    console.log(details);
    return this.http.post(url,details,httpOptions);
}
```

server side ->app.js:

```
app.post('/register',cors(),function(req,res){
  console.log(req.body);
})
```

The req.body must contain an object which is same as details in service.ts but getting undefined

Comment: Are you using `express` on the back-end? Have you added body-parser middleware `app.use(express.json());` or so?

Comment: Yes i am using express , i haven't added body-parser middle ware, is it required?

Comment: That was the issue the problem is solved, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Add body parser middleware before declaring the route:

```
const express = require('express');

// ...

app.use(express.json());

//...

app.post('/register', cors(), function(req,res) {
  console.log(req.body);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no body without body-parser.first install body-parser

```
npm install body-parser
```

Then use it in express like this:

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```