# Having problem with Sequelize not passing request parameters to DB

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am basically trying to make a post request to my DB using express.

I've tried assigning default values, then it posts just default values without parameters

My DB model looks like this:

```
const Player = sequelize.define('player', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,   
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    team: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    position: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },
  /*   imageUrl: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }, */
    description: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    pickedhero1: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    pickedhero2: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    pickedhero3: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
});

module.exports = Player;
```

Error I am getting is that fields can not be null

```
notNull Violation: player.name cannot be null,
notNull Violation: player.team cannot be null,
notNull Violation: player.position cannot be null,
notNull Violation: player.description cannot be null,
notNull Violation: player.pickedhero1 cannot be null,
notNull Violation: player.pickedhero2 cannot be null,
notNull Violation: player.pickedhero3 cannot be null
```

even tho I am passing this query

```
http://localhost:3000/api/playerz/?name=kkona&title=kkona&position=1&team=kkona&description=kkona&pickedhero1=1&pickedhero2=2&pickedhero3=3
```

My router file:

```
const express = require("express");
const Player = require('../models/player');
const router = express.Router();


router.post('/api/player/', (req, res, next) => {
    const title = req.body.title;
    const name = req.body.name;
    const team = req.body.team;
    const position = req.body.position;
    const description = req.body.description;
    const pickedhero1 = req.body.pickedhero1;
    const pickedhero2 = req.body.pickedhero2;
    const pickedhero3 = req.body.pickedhero3;
    Player.create( 
      req.body.title,
      req.body.name,
      req.body.team,
      req.body.description,
      req.body.pickedhero3,
      req.body.pickedhero2,
      req.body.pickedhero1
    ).then(result => {
        console.log(result);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
});


module.exports = router;
```

my app.js file looks like this:

```
const player = require('./routes/players');
...
app.use("/api/playerz", player);
...
sequelize.sync({force: true});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: You're passing an empty body and all values as a query-params. Those values are available via `req.query` not `req.body`

Answer (score 1):

You should use [req.query](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query) to access query params:

```
router.post('/api/player/', (req, res, next) => {
    const {
      title,
      name,
      team,
      position,
      description,
      pickedhero1,
      pickedhero2,
      pickedhero3
    } = req.query;

    Player.create({
      title,
      name,
      team,
      position,
      description,
      pickedhero1, 
      pickedhero2,
      pickedhero3
    }).then(result => {
        console.log(result);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

> JFYI: But ideally you should pass all those parameters in POST body, not it a query.

Comment: Yea, I tried but now I can not even post, I tried setting up body in postman aswell, didnt help, must have something with validation, reading the docs now

Comment: Which `content-type` are you trying to `POST` (e.g. `application/json`, `multipart/form-data`, etc)? In case of json you need to add body-parser middleware before using router.  [express.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57303416/i-made-a-http-post-request-in-client-sideangular-8-but-getting-undefined-in-se/57304045#57304045)

Comment: try `app.use(...)` instead of `app.subscribe(...)`

Comment: still the same, gonna check now with more options

Comment: I fixed it with some kind of sorcery I read in sequelize documents, it was validation stuff, thanks either way ♥

Answer (score 0):

1. user you are using query not body.( just a note: you should use body for POST)
2. when you create you should create like below:

   ```
   router.post('/api/player/', (req, res, next) => {
       const title = req.query.title;
       const name = req.query.name;
       const team = req.query.team;
       const position = req.query.position;
       const description = req.query.description;
       const pickedhero1 = req.query.pickedhero1;
       const pickedhero2 = req.query.pickedhero2;
       const pickedhero3 = req.query.pickedhero3;
       Player.create( {
         title: title,
         name: name,
         team: team,
         position: position,
         description: description,
         pickedhero1: pickedhero1, 
         pickedhero2: pickedhero2,
         pickedhero3: pickedhero3
       }).then(result => {
           console.log(result);
       }).catch(err => {
           console.log(err);
       });
   });
   ```

Comment: still the same error, I even set body in postman, it's the same, I think it has something to do with validation

Comment: the above code only works with the query request from your question. console log title before create and see if you can actually get value ?

Comment: I fixed it with some kind of sorcery I read in sequelize documents, it was validation stuff, thanks either way ♥